# How to fix this strange crash with keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, ios10, uiwindow

I have been seeing some odd crashes with the keyboard for some of the users that are live.
Looks like a KVO issue with UIWindow.

We are not adding any observers for key path `windowLevel`, so wondering what is causing this crash or how to debug this.

> An instance 0x12c653e70 of class UIRemoteKeyboardWindow was
>   deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.
>   Current observation info: NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x12d3e6100
>   NSKeyValueObservance 0x1196e01a0: Observer: 0x1273223f0, Key path:
>   windowLevel, Options:  Context: 0x0,
>   Property: 0x12c633980>

Also this crash is so random, I have never encountered this personally but got this via Crashlytics. Any help would be appreciated.
Have anyone else experienced similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you had provided some sample code. But I guess you may be removing all observers of your UIViewController at once and in wrong place. Move the code for removing observers to "viewWillDisappear" and it may solve it.

Another guess is you are changing an attribute of keyboard when it has been deallocated.

My other guess is that you may have a "weak" property of keyboard. If so, change it to "strong" and it will solve the problem.

Comment: I understand the question is too vague. I have received the crash via Crashlytics so no info on how did it happen and personally i have never seen this crash during the testing phase. I am just looking for insights if someone else faced the similar issue or experienced weird behaviour with UIRemoteKeyboardWindow.